# Including a file outside of local directory

Tags: directory, include, include-path

I have a project, laid out like this.

```
/Project Folder
    /Header file
    /Sub folder
        /Sub folder
           /Source file
```

If I want to include the header file in the source file, what path would I use inside of `#include ""`?

I am using Visual Studio 2022, with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of some friends.
if your target file is one directory out, then you would `#include "../targetFile.h"` for two it would be `#include "../../targetFile.h"`
and so on.